# How do I remove entities in Doctrine 2?

Tags: doctrine-orm

How do I remove entities in Doctrine 2?  I want to know how to do this through the command line and with PHP.  Thanks!

Edit:
I'm not sure if I'm asking this question right (I'm new to Doctrine).  I want to leave the Entity file in the directory, but I want to delete its table from the database.  This stems from Zend based modular architecture where modules can be installed/uninstalled without the module directory being removed.  If a module is uninstalled, I want its entities removed.  The opposite is also true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some looking into Doctrine's API and eventually figured it out:

```
$classes = array();
$entityManager = ...
$classes[] = $entityManager->getClassMetadata('Entities\MyEntity1');
$classes[] = $entityManager->getClassMetadata('Entities\MyEntity2');
$classes[] = $entityManager->getClassMetadata('Entities\MyEntity3');
$classes[] = $entityManager->getClassMetadata('Entities\MyEntity4');

//Doctrine Schema Tool
$st = new Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool( $entityManager );
$st->dropSchema($classes);
```

This will remove the tables associated with Entities\MyEntity1, 2, 3 and 4 from the database.

Also, using the exact same code above except the last line, the following methods are useful:

```
$st->createSchema($classes);
```

AND

```
$st->updateSchema($classes);
```

You can find all the info in Doctrine's documentation:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/api

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this. You have to manually remove associated database tables.

You can just remove \ORM annotation from entity if you want to exclude it from entity generation process.